# TFDCommand not finding the parameter but the parameter is in the command text

Tags: delphi, firedac

```
_cmd.CommandText.Text := 'INSERT INTO caixas(`operador`,`terminal`,`val_abertura,`turno`,'+
            '`data_abertura`,`nr_venda`,`STATUS`) VALUES( :oper , :term , :val_abertura , :turno , CURDATE() , 0 , 1)';
_cmd.ParamByName('oper').DataType := ftInteger;
_cmd.ParamByName('oper').Value := uid;
```

on runtime i get

> First chance exception at $7510A8B2. Exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Parameter 'oper' not found'. Process lrmgr.exe (5684)

And honestly i really don't know why, because i use this a lot(generating the CommandText at runtime) in a lot of different places in my code and only here i'm getting this problem

Comment: Remove the back quotes in the field list.

Comment: You have `_cmd.ResourceOptions.ParamCreate := false;` or `_cmd.ResourceOptions.PreprocessCmdText := false;` anywhere? Or some other option that turns off building the param list when CommandText changes?

Comment: why do your fields in your field list have back qoutes ? And why does `val_abertura` has such a quote on the left but not on the right ?